# how to resolve Task 'prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel' not found in project ':core'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Hi I am getting an error when I run the project, I have actually updated the gradle and gradle plugin versions and I am getting this error

can you please suggest what am I doing wrong here please

`Task 'prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel' not found in project ':core'.`

I added this to my gradle file already

```
tasks.register("prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel"){}
```

Added this to plugin section

```
id("com.android.application") version "7.1.1"
```

settings. gradle

```
pluginId.startsWith("com.android") -> useModule("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0")
```

project level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    val kotlinVersion by extra("1.5.21")
    dependencies {
        "classpath"("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0")
    }
}
```

one thing I noticed next to my build.gradle.kts - module version - `Module: app-android-core.unitTest` i don't see module version of the core any idea why that might have happened. this is whats in it

```
 import com.android.build.gradle.api.ApkVariant
import com.android.build.gradle.api.ApplicationVariant
import com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariantOutput
import com.android.build.gradle.api.TestVariant
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.BaseVariantOutputImpl
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.util.*

plugins {

    kotlin("android")
    kotlin("android.extensions")
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("kotlinx-serialization")

    // Needed for Firebase
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")

    // Needed for Crashlytics
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
    id("com.android.application") version "7.1.1"
}

// Load the signing info from the keystore.properties file
// (see https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)
val keystorePropFile = rootProject.file("core/keystore.properties")
val keystoreProp = Properties()
keystoreProp.load(FileInputStream(keystorePropFile))

val securePropFile = rootProject.file("core/secure.properties")
val secureProp = Properties()
secureProp.load(FileInputStream(securePropFile))

android {
    compileSdk = 31
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding = true
    }

    tasks.register("prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel"){}

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "io.xxxx.android"

        manifestPlaceholders["MapAPIKey"] = secureProp.getProperty("MAPS_API_KEY")

        minSdk = 23
        targetSdk = 30

        // Only get the FirebaseUI translations relevant to our app
        // (see https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth)
        resourceConfigurations += "en"

        // Export the local DB schema to the dbSchemas dir
        // (see https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions.html)
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += mapOf("room.schemaLocation" to "$projectDir/dbSchemas")
            }
        }

        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"
        }
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        // Clear the app's state between tests
        testInstrumentationRunnerArguments += mapOf("clearPackageData" to "true")

    }

    sourceSets {
        all {
            java.srcDir("src/$name/kotlin")
        }
        getByName("androidTest") {
            // Add the DB schemas dir as a test asset so we can test DB migrations
            // (see https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions.html)
            assets.srcDir(files("$projectDir/dbSchemas"))
        }
    }

    val debug = "debug"
    val release = "release"

    signingConfigs {
        create(release) {
            keyAlias = keystoreProp["keyAlias"] as? String
            keyPassword = keystoreProp["keyPassword"] as? String
            storeFile = file(keystoreProp["storeFile"]!!)
            storePassword = keystoreProp["storePassword"] as? String
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName(debug) {
            // We use the "version name suffix" instead of the "application ID suffix" so that we don't have to create
            // multiple apps in Firebase
            versionNameSuffix = "-$debug"
        }
        getByName(release) {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs[release]

            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), file("proguard-rules.pro"))
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions("brand", "type", "server")

    // We add different app ID suffix so we don't install different flavors overriding others, which might lead to
    // data issues in the device and unpredictable errors
    productFlavors {

    }

    applicationVariants.all {
 
    }

    applicationVariants.all(object : Action<ApplicationVariant> {

    })

    testVariants.all(object : Action<TestVariant> {
        override fun execute(variant: TestVariant) {
            renameApk(apkVariant = variant)
        }
    })

    // Enable the Test Orchestrator (see https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner.html#using-android-test-orchestrator)
    testOptions { execution = "ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR" }

    // Run instrumented tests on the release build
//    testBuildType = release

    // This fixes a compilation error caused by adding Coroutines lib twice (see https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1064)
    // TODO: Remove when this is no longer happening
    packagingOptions { exclude("META-INF/*") }

    lintOptions { isAbortOnError = false }
    dynamicFeatures += mutableSetOf()
}

/**
 * Renames the APK generated for the [apkVariant] received.
 */
fun renameApk(apkVariant: ApkVariant) {
    apkVariant.outputs.all(object : Action<BaseVariantOutput> {

        override fun execute(output: BaseVariantOutput) {
            (output as BaseVariantOutputImpl).outputFileName =
            "${apkVariant.name}-${apkVariant.versionName?.replace("-debug","")}.apk"
        }
    })
}

// Necessary to use Kotlin experimental features, such as @Parcelize
androidExtensions {
    isExperimental = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk7"))

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.2.2")

    // Used to trigger a restart programmatically
    implementation ("com.jakewharton:process-phoenix:2.1.2")

    // Chatbot feature
    implementation(project(":chatbot"))

    // See https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1")
    implementation("androidx.collection:collection-ktx:1.2.0")
    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.0")
    kapt("android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0")
    implementation("androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0")
    implementation("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2")
    implementation("androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.5.21")

    implementation("androidx.paging:paging-runtime:3.1.0")

    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0")
    // Used to manage preferences
    implementation("androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1")

    // Used to send HTTP requests
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0") {
        // Avoid duplicated import of Gson
        exclude(group = "com.google.code.gson", module = "gson")
    }
    // Necessary to parse responses as strings (used in HttpService)
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0")
    // Used to log requests and responses in Retrofit (for debug builds)
    debugImplementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.1")

    // Used to send HTTP requests in xxxx-common
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1")

    // Used to communicate with WebSockets
    implementation("com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet:0.2.4")
    implementation("com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-protocol-websocket-okhttp:0.2.4")
    implementation("com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-stream-adapter-coroutines:0.2.4")
    implementation("com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-message-adapter-gson:0.2.4")
    implementation("com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-lifecycle-android:0.2.4") {
        // Exclude this module to avoid a minify compilation issue (see https://github.com/Tinder/Scarlet/issues/59)
        exclude(group = "com.github.tinder", module = "scarlet")
    }

    // Used for crashes with Firebase
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.5")

    // Used for sending feedback
    implementation("com.instabug.library:instabug:10.4.1")
    // Necessary to add network logs to Instabug reports
    implementation("com.instabug.library:instabug-with-okhttp-interceptor:10.4.1")

    // Used for authentication with Firebase
    implementation("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.0.0")

    // Necessary for Facebook sign in (see https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)
    implementation("com.facebook.android:facebook-login:12.0.0")

    // Used for analytics
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:20.0.0")

    // Used for tracking user interactions
    implementation("com.uxcam:uxcam:3.3.0@aar")

    // Used for receiving push messages
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0")

    // Used to get remote configuration from Firebase (e.g., for force update)
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx:21.0.1")

    // Used for dynamic links
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links-ktx:21.0.0")

    // Used for reading QR codes
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3")

    // Used to easily run tasks in the background
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.2")

    // Needed to use java.time-like APIs for date and time (see https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)
    implementation("com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.2")

    // Used to load images from URLs
    implementation("com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828")

    // Used to show tool tips
    implementation("com.github.skydoves:balloon:1.3.3")

    // Used for creating charts
    implementation("com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0")

    // Used fore creating custom DatePicker / TimePicker dialogs (see https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/releases)
    implementation("com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.2.3")

    // Used for DI, to make classes configurable for automated tests
    implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.28.1")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.1")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.26")

    // Used for payments
    implementation("com.stripe:stripe-android:16.3.0")

    // Test libs

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:3.3.0")
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.9.3")
    testImplementation("org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:2.2")
    testImplementation("androidx.room:room-testing:2.3.0")
    testImplementation("com.jraska.livedata:testing-ktx:1.1.2")
    testImplementation("android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1")
    testImplementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.4.1")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.3.3")

    androidTestImplementation("androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:rules:1.4.0")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:runner:1.4.0")
    androidTestUtil("androidx.test:orchestrator:1.4.0")

    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.4.0")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.4.0")

    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0")
}
```

project structure looks like this

[image]